# Dúvidas sobre Script Coroutine c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Fiz um script junto ao coroutine, mais meio que não funciona msm não dando erro
A minha real intenção é fazer com que botão tenha um atraso de até 10 segundos antes de fazer a transição para outra canva

poderiam me da uma força?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class canvas2ecanvas3 : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject canvas2,canvas3;
   public void start(){
      StartCoroutine(cena ());
   }
   IEnumerator cena(){
      canvas2.SetActive(false);
      canvas3.SetActive(true);
      yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);
   }
   public void voltar(){
      canvas2.SetActive(true);
      canvas3.SetActive(false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Posta seu código em texto, ajuda na hora de copiar e colar pra te ajudar ;)

Comment: tentarei mais ele não está indo

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa colocar o `yield` antes dos comandos que quer executar. Da forma atual o código está executando os comandos antes do `yield` e depois esperando x segundos pra não fazer mais nada. Exemplo:

```
IEnumerator cena()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);
    canvas2.SetActive(false);
    canvas3.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: pior de tudo é que já tentei desse jeito, mais irei testar novamente pra ver

Comment: Michelly, a sugestão funcionou? Se sim, considere marcar a resposta como aceita, ok? :) Além de recompensar quem te ajudou, vc também auxilia o sistema a funcionar melhor.